# How to get two mysql querie results in one JSON array?

Tags: php, mysql, json

in my current project I have to create a JSON array, in which for each day a status with a colour is displayed in a calendar (FullCalendar) and additionally a button with a link is to be displayed for all days where an event is planned.

For this I have two SELECT's which both work on their own. I have already tried some things how to put the results of both SELECT's into one JSON array, but I keep getting the error 'Undefinded Variable'.

How do I have to pack the results of the two SELEC T's put together that all results are displayed correctly?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include "../../../includes/db.php";

if(isset($_GET['team_id'])) {
   $team_id = $_GET['team_id'];
}

$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT date FROM date");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   $date = $row['date'];

   $team_planner_user_status_present = 1;
   $team_planner_user_status_absent = 2;
   $team_planner_user_status_reservation = 3;
   $stmt1 = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
                                   (
                                      SELECT COUNT(*)
                                      FROM team_planner_user 
                                      INNER JOIN user ON team_planner_user.user_id = user.user_id 
                                      WHERE user.team_id = ?
                                      AND team_planner_user.date = ?
                                      AND team_planner_user.team_planner_user_status = ?
                                   ) AS present,
                                   (
                                      SELECT COUNT(*)
                                      FROM team_planner_user 
                                      INNER JOIN user ON team_planner_user.user_id = user.user_id 
                                      WHERE user.team_id = ?
                                      AND team_planner_user.date = ?
                                      AND team_planner_user.team_planner_user_status = ?
                                   ) AS absent,
                                   (
                                      SELECT COUNT(*)
                                      FROM team_planner_user 
                                      INNER JOIN user ON team_planner_user.user_id = user.user_id 
                                      WHERE user.team_id = ?
                                      AND team_planner_user.date = ?
                                      AND team_planner_user.team_planner_user_status = ?
                                   ) AS reservation
                                ");
$stmt1->bind_param("sssssssss", $team_id, $date, $team_planner_user_status_present, 
                                $team_id, $date, $team_planner_user_status_absent, 
                                $team_id, $date, $team_planner_user_status_reservation);
$stmt1->execute();
$result1 = $stmt1->get_result();
while($row1 = $result1->fetch_array()) {
            
    $present = $row1['present'];
    $absent = $row1['absent'];
    $reservation = $row1['reservation'];

    if($present >= 5) {
        $color = '#a1ff9e';
    } else if($present + $reservation >= 5) {
        $color = '#fcff9e';
    } else {
        $color = '#ff9e9e';
    }
}

$stmt1->close();

$stmt2 =$connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM game_planned INNER JOIN game_role ON game_planned.match_role_id = game_role.match_role_id WHERE team_id = ? AND game_planned_date = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param("ss", $team_id, $date);
$stmt2->execute();
$result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()) {
    $match_role_name = $row2['match_role_name'];
    $game_planned_id = $row2['game_planned_id'];
}

$data[] = array(
    'start' => $date,
    'display' => 'background',
    'color' => $color,
);

if($result->num_rows === 0) {
    echo "";
} else {
    $data[] = array(
        'title' => $match_role_name,
        'url' => 'http://localhost/r6team-redesign/team/team.php?team=details-match-plan&match_planned_id='.$game_planned_id,
        'start' => $date,
    );
}
}

$stmt->close();

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Hi. Does the first stmt->execute() return any data? $data is declared inside the first while() but it is used after it. I am wondering if the number of lines is zero and the variable $data was not declared yet - the code wound not enter on the first while.

Comment: Yes. $data ist only the variable to store the array